# Is there any methodology or pattern to picking better stats to emphasize for location and other world encounters?

Tags: arkham-horror

I know this of the 6 basic stats

- speed: for moving through arkham
- sneak: for evading
- fight: for combat and gate closing
- lore: for spell casting and gate closing
- luck: for....shrug. Encountery random stuff.

Obviously all of these stats are tested in encounters as well, but is there any predictable way to their occurrence in tests in these encounters? For instance does the Science Building more often check Will or the Library Lore? It feels random what stat gets tested most of the time, so short of the reasons in the bulleted items, I often feel like I'm flailing just randomly picking which stat to boost during upkeep if I'm not specifically dealing with gate closing or monster encounters, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, different locations do skew toward different skills.

If you really want to know, you can look at something like [this cheat sheet](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/43768/arkham-horror-location-encounter-statistics). I personally think that kind of spoils the game a bit, though. It's not as bad as if you just looked through the encounter cards yourself, but it still takes out a bit of surprise and fun in playing. The one broad rule is that encounters do depend on luck a bit more often than other skills in general, since they're the only place it's really used.

The kind of edge you can get from this knowledge really isn't too large, though. The most likely skill needed in an area might not be much more likely than the other skills, and some locations are probably pretty evenly balanced. Your skill focus is often substantially restricted by what you need to do to move/fight. And it's certainly possible to do quite well in the game without that little edge. So I think you might as well just play a bunch of games and learn that way!

Answer (score 0):

I feel that the location icons (p24 of [rulebook](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Arkham_Horror/AH_Rules_internat.pdf)) can give some hints to what skills you need.  Specifically stamina, sanity and spells.  I also think the game did a good job of making the areas *generally* (but not altogether) lean to logically what you might encounter in them.  Like lore for the Spell shop.

I am spoiler sensitive so I have no proof, akin to the same reason I did not review the cheatsheet linked in @Jefromi's answer.  Perhaps it contradicts what I have said.
But 2 cents.

Comment: The icons are for what you might get, not what skilla you need. Needing lore for spells I can understand (not sure if it's true but it's possible). But what skill are you saying you'd need for a potential encounter that'd grant stamina or sanity?

Comment: @Jefromi I did not say but did say I am anti-spoiler so also do not intend to.  If you think this (intentional) vagueness makes for a bad answer, I am open to that and can delete it.  It does not change what I believe to be true.  I imagine if people want the spoiler they can look through the cards (or link you posted) and see for themselves.

Comment: Being anti spoiler is great, your answer just makes is sound like you're saying there's an obvious matchup between potential rewards and skills, and I don't see one.

Comment: @Jefromi I don't think it's obvious (and that was not my intention of writing), I think I've played the game too much and have a "bit" of metagaming knowledge now when I play that I can't get rid of=)  Would removing the "specifically" line help make the answer better?  Do you feel the answer can be useful without an example?